# Using a much larger than necessary carboy

Tags: carboy

This is a very simple question. I have a batch of German wine that will yield 2.5 gallons. Is there any issue with using a 6 gallon glass carboy to let it ferment in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be fine.  The extra headspace could possibly encourage oxidation, but if you don't open it frequently you should be fine.